# Getting Trace Keyboard back after Android 4.1.1 update on HTC Desire X

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 4.1-jelly-bean, htc-sense, htc, htc-desire-x

I have a HTC Desire X. It was running 4.0.4. Yesterday I updated OS to 4.1.1.
This took away the Trace keyboard - is there a way to get Trace keyboard back after the 4.1.1. update. If not, can I revert back to 4.0.4? I am not rooted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed next 2 OTA updates & got my trace keyboard back. The first one was a small 10MB OS Update which was still Android 4.1.1 but Software Number as 2.22.720.7. This required booting after upgrade. The next was a HTC Sense Update which required no booting and got me my Trace keyboard back. The stupid Power saver notification which came with the Jelly Bean update is still not gone but Trace keyboard back is good enough. Never going to update the OS again on this phone!!!